# Why does Jekyll not load images

Tags: jekyll

I'm new to jekyll and I'm attempting to setup a user site for github. I'm using [this](https://mmistakes.github.io/hpstr-jekyll-theme/) template which has remained unchange apart from minor `_config.yml` details.

I've edited the the `/index.html` front matter to have a new image instead of the default `abstract-1.jpg`. However, the image just doesn't load when serving the site. I can use any of the images that came with the template but I can't use ones I've downloaded. Also it can't load external images.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're speaking about a Github project repository made to serve with Github Pages.

Just set the `baseurl` variable in your `_config.yml` to `/repositoryName`.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Do have any ideas about why it seemed to be ok with certain images but not others?

Comment: From `index.html` the relative link `images/myimg.jpg` will work but this link will not work from `/about/index.html`. `{{site.baseurl}}/images/myimg.jpg` will work from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Owner/Author Information
>
> Change your name, and avatar photo (200x200 pixels or larger), email, and social networking URLs. If you want to link to an external image on Gravatar or something similar you’ll need to edit the path in head.html since it assumes it is located in /images.

Try that? Source: https://mmistakes.github.io/hpstr-jekyll-theme/